# Does anyone have a well written php unit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing

So I am new to unit testing. I'm through a book and couple of tutorials but I still have some doubts about the exact proper implementation.

I am searching for a well written unit test, because the sample examples that are based on the relationship of 2 or 3 classes cannot answer my remaining questions. I'd like to see some real world scenarios of proper coding that ensure long-term maintainability. The bigger the project the better. Does somebody have a well written test, or does somebody know a well written test that's available somewhere on the web? Thanks for help!

Comment: Pick a couple of large open source projects which have test coverage and look at their test suite.

Comment: A well written unit test, is one that adheres to good coding standards and tests the code. There's no magic formula, it's effort and ability.

Comment: Unit tests should never be based on relationships between classes, that's the whole point of mocking

Comment: @MarkBaker Yeah, that is what I read and what I tend to believe. The point when I lose ground is I wrote a 20 line function test for a 3 line function. That seemed like a little bit of overkill for me. Is this a normal thing to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Github to browse sources of various popular open source projects like Joomla.

Here is the link to Joomla CMS https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms and here is the link to Joomla Framework https://github.com/joomla/joomla-framework.

Mentioned Joomla because it is my favorite; especially Joomla Framework. You may also try others like CakePHP, Code Igniter etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just browse through most of well known open source projects on Github.

- [Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/master/tests)
- [Zend](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/tests)
- [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop/unitTests)

To name but a few.